# Configure eslint with coffeescript eslintrc

Tags: coffeescript, eslint, eslintrc

I am trying to configure eslint with a coffeescript file with the following code. But so far the configuration is not being read correctly.

```js
# .eslintrc.js
require('coffeescript/register')
require('./.eslintrc.coffee')
```

```coffee
# .eslintrc.coffee
config =
  root: true
  env:
    node: true
  extends: [
    'plugin:prettier/recommended'
    'plugin:vue/recommended'
    '@vue/standard'
  ]
  parserOptions:
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  rules:
    'prettier/prettier': 'error'
    'no-console': if process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' then 'error' else 'off'
    'no-debugger': if process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' then 'error' else 'off'

module.exports = config
```

Unfortunately, this is the result.

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/eslint --print-config test.js
{
  "env": {},
  "globals": {},
  "parser": null,
  "parserOptions": {},
  "plugins": [],
  "rules": {},
  "settings": {}
}
```

Other things I've tried unsuccessfully are:

```js
# .eslintrc.js
require('coffeescript/register')
module.exports = require('./.eslintrc.coffee')
```

```coffee
# .eslintrc.coffee
config =
  root: true
  env:
    node: true
  extends: [
    'plugin:prettier/recommended'
    'plugin:vue/recommended'
    '@vue/standard'
  ]
  parserOptions:
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  rules:
    'prettier/prettier': 'error'
    'no-console': if process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' then 'error' else 'off'
    'no-debugger': if process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' then 'error' else 'off'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting an answer since I couldn't find it anywhere:

```js
# .eslintrc.js
require('coffeescript/register')
module.exports = require('./.eslintrc.coffee')
```

```coffee
# .eslintrc.coffee
module.exports =
  root: true
  env:
    node: true
  extends: [
    'plugin:prettier/recommended'
    'plugin:vue/recommended'
    '@vue/standard'
  ]
  parserOptions:
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  rules:
    'prettier/prettier': 'error'
    'no-console': if process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' then 'error' else 'off'
    'no-debugger': if process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' then 'error' else 'off'
```

That's right, requires double `module.exports`.

I'm too far gone in other languages to know why...

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/eslint --print-config test.js
{
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true
  },
  "globals": {
    "document": false,
    "navigator": false,
    "window": false
  },
  "parser": "/home/worthlessjavascriptcomma/test/node_modules/vue-eslint-parser/index.js",
  "parserOptions": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "ecmaVersion": 2018,
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": [
    "prettier",
    "vue",
    "standard",
    "promise",
    "node",
    "import"
  ],
  ...
```

Does someone has another option?